# ASP.NET Core deployment options

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, owin, .net-core

We just started using ASP.NET Core in our development. There are a few open questions I have not really found useful resources for. What would be the best-practices or differences between the following, and are they all valid?

**ASP.NET Core + .NET 4.6**

1) On IIS

2) Standalone on OWIN

3) OWIN + IIS

**ASP.NET Core + .NET Core:**

1) On IIS (published)

2) Standalone Kestrel (development and test environment)

3) Standalone Kestrel + IIS reverse-proxy (QA and production

Thanks!

EDIT: My title and question options were not valid, so I changed them to reflect my current understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure if `Asp.Net Core` has OWIN at all.

Comment: Is it so that Asp.Net Core can run on IIS or as stand-alone on Kestrel, or then run Asp.Net Core on .Net 4.6 on IIS or as stand-alone on OWIN?

Comment: @afsharm See https://github.com/ymoradi/OwinAspNetCore This is a sample app using owin, asp.net web api odata, signalr, etc on ASP.NET Core pipeline with full .net framework, and this is a sample of using nancy on asp.net core and .net core using owin pipeline. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringAMinimalWebAPIWithNETCoreAndNancyFX.aspx ASP.NET Core is pipeline and server independent.

Comment: @LexLi Your comment is obviously wrong, ASP.NET Core is pipeline and server independent, you can use Owin pipeline and owin servers in asp.net core, in both .net core & full .Net, see my previous comment.

Comment: @YasserMoradi Thank you for your recommendation. Having odata with asp.net core (even in full framework) is very useful for us.

Comment: @LexLi Owin is standard, and it has several implementations. You can use asp.net core pipeline inside of owin pipeline, you can use owin pipeline inside asp.net core pipeline, and you can host asp.net core apps on owin hosts. I'm not talking about katana, which is an implementation only. See http://owin.org My app can run on top of asp.net core and helios, and I can run it on windows service with owin http host listener, and I can run it on ASP.NET & IIS using katana. How do you say it is all about middlewares only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) runs on full framework (.NET 4.5, 4.6) too. So for ASP.NET core Kestrel + reverse proxy is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommanded to not expose standalone (kestrel) server directly but behind a (reverse)proxy. Like IIS, apache or nginx. See [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html?highlight=nginx#kestrel)

Comment: if IIS is used as a reverse proxy, what would be the reason to run Kestrel at all? Why not just use IIS then?

Comment: @user1340582 Because IIS is windows-only :) ?

Comment: @goaty well sure, but it's the same story on Linux. If you would require JBoss as reverse proxy for Kestrel on Linux, your first question would be to ask, why your app can't run within JBoss itself :)

Comment: @user1340582 Kestrel is a managed library which parses the request and gives you HttpContext. IIS/nginx... is the web server that handles load balancing, filtering, app lifecycle... asp.net core is completely decoupled from the webserver :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of complete scenarios:

For automated E2E testing you can use Owin Test Server or ASP.NET Core Test Server
For Development/QA/Production you can use IIS/Kestrel , IIS/WebListener (Preview and Windows Only, but has benefits), IIS/Owin(Katana), IIS/Nowin.
Remember that ASP.NET Core is server and pipeline independent, you can use asp.net core pipeline and use owin pipeline inside of that, you can use owin pipeline and use asp.net core pipeline inside of that. You can even develop servers and pipelines from scratch, (Was really useful for me in one of my applications). To start, I recommend you to use asp.net core with full .net framework with owin & asp.net core pipelines together. You can use ASP.NET Core features such ASP.NET Core MVC 1, and you can use ASP.NET Web API OData, Signalr, web hooks, thinktecuture identity server based on owin side by side. And wait for ASP.NET Core / .NET core implementations of Signalr, thinktecuture identity server 4 etc. Remember that .NET Core is not .NET Standards 2.0 complaint. Your migration will become easier a lot after that.
This is a sample working application:
https://github.com/ymoradi/OwinAspNetCore